# systemd-journald system logs are not persistent across boots despite Storage=persistent

Tags: systemd, arch-linux, journald

I recently got a problem with systemd not preserving logs from previous boots. I checked several answers here and elsewhere but haven't found a solution.

the problem is that the user log gets persistent across boots but system logs are not

`/etc/systemd/journald.conf`

```
[Journal]
Storage=persistent
SystemMaxUse=500M
SystemMaxFiles=5
```

`journalctl -b -1`

```
[root@2ba2de9e /var/log/journal] # journalctl --system -b -1
Data from the specified boot (-1) is not available: No such boot ID in journal
```

I'm using archlinux arm on some raspberry pis

versions `4.14.24-1-ARCH`
`systemd 237.64-1`
`systemd-sysvcompat 237.64-1`

Anyone has an idea why this is occurring? on my desktop machine this is working without problems?

Comment: Does `/var/log/journal` exist on persistent, read-write media?

Comment: yes. no cleanup scripts or sth comparable.

Comment: Are the permissions of /var/log/journal the correct ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that journald is removing the old logs because you're short on diskspace. (You didn't mention how long after boot the `-b -1` is not working, so I don't know if you have many logs from the current boot at that time.)

You have `SystemMaxUse=500M` configured, but journald might decide to use less than 500MB if you don't have too much free diskspace. There is also a `SystemKeepFree=...` setting, which defaults to 15% of the size of the filesystem (or 4GB, whatever is smaller) and journald will enforce that limit more strongly than how much space you allow. If you have your `/var/log/journal` in a tight partition, maybe that might be part of the issue.

You can use some commands to check how much space journald is using, such as:

```
$ journalctl --disk-usage
```

And you and also see how many boots (and what are their times and IDs) journald knows about with:

```
$ journalctl --list-boots
```

These might also help shed a light on your issue...

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

My distro came with this file: `/etc/systemd/journald.conf.d/volatile-storage.conf`
It had the following line

```
Storage=volatile
```

The volatile part needs to be changed to persistent, otherwise the change at `/etc/systemd/journal.conf` gets ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on [mirr](https://serverfault.com/a/1102108/94442) answer, for `Storage=volatile` and `Storage=auto` to work, the `/var/log/journal` directory must exist, and some distributions don't provide this location by default.

So you need to create and instruct `journald` to flush whatever is in memory to it.

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/journal     ## Enable persistent logging
sudo journalctl --flush
```